# Can Javascript overwrite a HTTPOnly cookie?

Tags: cookies, web

Can Javascript overwrite or delete a HTTPOnly cookie?

In more detail: Suppose the user's browser has a cookie for `example.com` with the HTTPOnly flag set, say `session=552..e0`.  Suppose the user visits a page on `example.com`.  Can Javascript running on that page overwrite the cookie with a new cookie that does not have the HTTPOnly cookie flag set?  Will that effectively delete the existing HTTPOnly cookie?  Can I count on browsers to prevent this?

---

Research I've done: The Google Browser Security Handbook [says](https://code.google.com/archive/p/browsersec/wikis/Part2.wiki):

> no specific thought was given to preventing JavaScript from overwriting httponly cookies

but I know that those pages are quite old right now, and that quote is not entirely explicit about what is possible.  A table on the same page says that on MSIE, Firefox 3, Opera, and Chrome, Javascript cannot overwrite HTTPOnly cookies, but Safari and Android browsers can -- but again, that's a very old resource.  [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Creating_cookies) is not clear on this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you might not be able to rewrite the cookie you might be able to shadow it. The specific behavior depends on the browser though. With Firefox I can set a site-global HttpOnly cookie with `path=/` and a JavaScript cookie with a different path. If I visit this path then I get both cookies:

```
# In server response
Set-Cookie: Foo=http; HttpOnly; Path=/

# In document script
document.cookie = "Foo=js; path=/f;"

# Request when visiting path /f
Cookie: Foo=js; Foo=http;
```

In Chrome though it shows in the request only a single cookie, the one with the HttpOnly flag. It has the other cookie stored locally though and can access it with JavaScript.

For more on this see also [Cookies Lack Integrity: Real-World Implications](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity15/sec15-paper-zheng.pdf) from Usenix 2015. The findings there might be no longer fully true though since the browsers might have changed their behavior in the meantime.